# playing and stopping audio from two different buttons

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm running this code for pausing the song but it obliviously doesn't work.
I can't access the variables of the first button from the second one, so I can't pause the song.
How do you think I could do that?
I'm using the naudio library cause I wanted to put the audio file as resource.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    MemoryStream mp3file = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.musica1);                
    Mp3FileReader mp3reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3file);
    var waveOut = new WaveOut();
    waveOut.Init(mp3reader);
    waveOut.Play();

            if (pausa)
            {
                waveOut.Pause();
            }


    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pausa = true;
    }
```

Comment: are you familiar with `Scope` you can't access local variables in one method from outside of another.. this is basics here is a good like to use at your disposal and future references.. I would suggest using it until you become more proficient [C# Basics - Variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_variables.htm) || [C# Encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_encapsulation.htm) declare `pausa` as a auto property or a public property at the class level. also `If  you are going to post code post all relevat code where do you declare pausa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to restructure your code. The problem is that in your `button3_Click` method, you are loading and playing your MP3, but then the function immediately terminates. The `if` statement won't be continuously checked, which is what I think you assume will happen. Therefore, clicking `button2` will simply change the state of `pausa` but this doesn't affect anything.

One way would be to make all the variables (`mp3file`, `mp3reader`, and `waveOut`) declared at the class level, then put the rest of the code inside `button3_Click` into, say, your form's `Load` event handler.

```
// These variables are declared at the class level
MemoryStream mp3file;
Mp3FileReader mp3reader;
WaveOut waveOut;

...

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mp3file = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.musica1);                
    mp3reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3file);
    waveOut = new WaveOut();
    waveOut.Init(mp3reader);    
}
```

Now, your `buttonX_Click` functions can look like this (assuming `button3` is your Play button and `button2` is your Pause button):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    waveOut.Play();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    waveOut.Pause();
}
```

Because `waveOut` is declared at the class level, both buttons have access to it, and can therefore play and pause at will. You don't need `pausa` anymore, unless of course you need to know the playing state elsewhere in the program.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the var keyword, so I've just copied `var waveOut = new WaveOut(); ` and I was unable to keep it out of the method. I solved the problem a couple of days ago declaring waveOut as `WaveOut waveOut;` , thank you anyway :D that was a newbie question tough ^^ it was easy